# Як правильно: «Жюрі» чи «Журі»

Tags: вживання-слів, синоніми, росіянізм

Як правильно: **«жюрі»** чи **«журі»**?

[Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%96%D1%83%D1%80%D1%96) не виключає обидва варіанти:

> **Журі́**, **жюрі** (фр. *jury*, від лат. *juro* «присягаю»)

Мені цікаво, чи правильно це?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Правильно: **журі**.

---

Вікі багато чого не виключає, причини: збереження [старого] московського варіянту, неточне тлумачення правопису, відсутність прикладу.

Але чинний — 2015 року — правопис надає чіткий приклад:

[§ 90. J](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm#par90)

> **1.** Відповідно до вимови **j** у словах французького походження передається через **ж**: *Жером* (Jérôme), *жабо* (jabot), *Жанна* (Jeanne), ***журі*** (jury);

Також зазначу, що історично в українській мові **ж** переважно суто тверда. Хіба є випадки, коли частково помʼякшується, наприклад *лівобережжя*.

---

Щодо [старого] московського варіянту, то ось доказ:

[Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 2, 1971. — Стор. 550.](http://sum.in.ua/s/zhjuri)

> **ЖЮРІ**, *невідм., сер.* Група спеціалістів, яка вирішує питання про присудження премій та нагород на конкурсах, виставках, змаганнях і т. ін. >
>   *На естраді з'являється жюрі конкурсу — п'ять шановних старичків в чорних фраках, з нотами в руках* (Іван Кочерга, II, 1956, 173); *Жюрі фестивалю нагородило дипломами I ступеня два українські колективи* (Мистецтво, 6, 1958, 23).

Але електронний словник справедливо вказує несумісність:

> Увага! Подане тут оригінальне написання реєстрового слова є застарілим.